# " INTO OUTFILE " statement terminated without completion locks the file

Tags: java, mysql, sql, into-outfile

i am creating a csv by using "INTO OUTFILE" statement for a mysql database. the database is huge 0.4 million records. i am using java program from eclipse to connect to mysql database and give this OUTFILE query. sometimes after running the query from program i do not want to wait for the whole query completion.so i terminate the java program from eclipse. but when i do this i find that the csv file is locked. i cant copy or delete it . i am using windows 7 . i close the eclipse application and find the csv file is still locked in the sense even as administrator i cant delete it. how can i unlock the csv file without having to restart the computer.

Comment: Solution : stopping  and starting mysql did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [unlocker](http://unlocker.en.softonic.com/) to determine which application still holds a lock on the file and to remove that lock.